# Location of shortcuts pinned to Win8/8.1 Start Screen

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-8.1

I was trying to change the icon of a pinned icons. On the taskbar I found the icon shortcuts to be in either of two locations:

- `C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\myapp.exe`
- `C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\ImplicitAppShortcuts\RANDOM_DIRNAME\myapp.exe`

  - Where `RANDOM_DIRNAME` is in my case `2290c79480996b2e`

So I update the icon on the shortcut in here and it updates in the taskbar. However it is not updating to the one pinned on start screen of Windows 8 and 8.1 does anyone know in which folder these shortcuts are located?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan you're correct. My addon is giving them option to badge their profile, so  I have to search in all the right directories and do it for them, its with their permission though. User won't be happy if I tell them for each profile go to a bunch of different folders, right click > props > change icon > browser > find icon > ok, repeat haha

Comment: Consider using [SysInternals' Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which files are being accessed when you update the shortcuts manually, then you can code for those locations as needed.

Comment: I tested as you said @RemyLebeau and found it seems to be `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` is this valid for you? The shortcut may be in a subdir in that folder.